# Excel VBA IN keyword

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Is there a better way to code this in VBA:

```
If x = 'a' or x = 'b' or x ='c' or x = 'd' then
...action
End if
```

The IN keyword would come very handy here:

```
If x IN ('a','b','c','d') then
action
End If
```

--> but VBA doesn't recognise IN. Is there an alternative keyword to it in the syntax?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the **FILTER()** function is to see if an item appears in an array:

```
Sub FilterExample()
    ary = Split("a,b,c,d", ",")
    x = "b"
    If Filter(ary, x)(o) <> "" Then
        MsgBox "match found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Gary's Student's answer in its current form will cause an error when a match is not found. I believe the following is better:

```
x = "a"
If UBound(Filter(Array("a", "b", "c", "d"), x)) > -1 Then
    MsgBox "Match found"
End If
```

I do comment though that when x is an empty string the filter function returns the whole array. So if x is an empty string the above will always return a match. The below accounts for this

```
x = "a"
If UBound(Filter(Array("a", "b", "c", "d"), x)) > -1 And x <> vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Match found"
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Something of this sort can be achieved with the [`Select Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) statement:

```vb
Select Case x
    Case "a", "b", "c", "d"
        ' ... action
End Select
```